# What is best way to fetch files from server in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, http-get

I am tring to develop a app using Flutter Web to provide a gallery of mediafiles stored in an apache server. Currently I am using Dio to get files as bytes and then call saveAs javascript function to downloand files to client computer. While this approach works for small sized files, it gives out of memory error for big files in browser. My code to get files is as follows. Can you suggest me a better way to get files? Thanks.

```
response = await dio.get(
medialink,
    cancelToken: cancelToken,
    onReceiveProgress: (rcv, total) {
    if (total != -1) {
      setState(() {
        progress = ((rcv / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0);
      });
      if (rcv == total) {
        setState(() {
          isDownloaded = true;
          downloading = false;
        });
      }
    }
    else {
      print("-1");
    }
  },
    //Received data with List<int>
    options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
        followRedirects: false,
        validateStatus: (status) { return status! < 500; }
    ),
  );
```

Comment: A better way to approach this without making user to download the app is to create an api that shares the url of the images.